# Knock out in a ul displaying weird. How can I Fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js, data-binding

I want my "fill in" text to be aligned properly with the check box and text entry. The top one always displays correctly aligned.

Also when the bottom text box is empty the "fill in" message displays on the top line not where its suppose to on the second line.

The images below illustrate the problem. The span text only shows if the text entries are blank.

[image]
[image]

```
 <ul class="answerList" data-bind="foreach: answers">

     <li>
     <span data-bind="text: answerError"></span>
     <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: id, attr: { name: 'Questions[' + $parentContext.$index() + '].Answers[' + $index() + '].Id' }" />
     <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: isCorrect, attr: { name: 'Questions[' + $parentContext.$index() + '].Answers[' + $index() + '].IsCorrect' }" />
     <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $index(), attr: { name: 'Questions[' + $parentContext.$index() + '].Answers[' + $index() + '].SortOrder' }" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: text, attr: { 'name': 'Questions[' + $parentContext.$index() + '].Answers[' + $index() + '].Text' }" />
     <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isCorrect, attr: { 'name': 'question' + $parentContext.$index() + 'IsCorrect' }" />
     <a data-bind="click: remove, visible: removeEnabled" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-remove icon-white">x</i></a>

  </li>
 </ul>
```

My css

```
         .answerList {
            li {
                list-style: none;


                input[type='text'] {
                    width: 90%;
                    float: right;
                }

                input[type="checkbox"] {
                    margin-right: 10px;
                    float: right;
                }

            }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your layout issues are largely CSS, which you don't include in your question.

Comment: updated the issue with the css.

Comment: The question is extremely unclear. There's either superfluous (knockoutjs) code, or missing (javascript) code. Since it's mostly a layout issue I'd hazard a guess this could be reproduced without all the (implied) JS. In addition the CSS seems to be less or sass instead, the term "Fill in" from the screenshot doesn't appear in the code at all, and the html hints at a use of bootstrap which isn't mentioned or referred to. Please update the question, follow the guidance in [mcve] to make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me how you want various situations to work, but I've simplified your code a bit and made the snippet below so you and others can play with it. I think you should do away with `float` and try different options for [`display`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp), possibly the `table-*` settings, or maybe a [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```js
function Obj(name) {
  this.text = name;
}
Obj.prototype = {
  answerError: 'Fill in',
  isCorrect: function() {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function() {},
  removeEnabled: function() { return Math.random() > 0.5 ? true : false; }
};

vm = {
  answers: [
    new Obj('one'),
    new Obj('two'),
    new Obj('three')
  ]
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.answerList li {
  list-style: none;
}
.answerList li input[type='text'] {
  width: 90%;
}
.answerList li input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul class="answerList" data-bind="foreach: answers">

  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: answerError"></span>
    <!--input type="hidden" data-bind="value: id, attr: { name: 'Questions[' + $parentContext.$index() + '].Answers[' + $index() + '].Id' }" />
    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: isCorrect, attr: { name: 'Questions[' + $parentContext.$index() + '].Answers[' + $index() + '].IsCorrect' }" />
    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $index(), attr: { name: 'Questions[' + $parentContext.$index() + '].Answers[' + $index() + '].SortOrder' }" /-->
    <a data-bind="click: remove, visible: removeEnabled()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-remove icon-white">x</i></a>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isCorrect" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: text, " />

  </li>
</ul>
```